# Strange Array and cannot do replacement

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this Array from an API.  I want to replace the word 'test' with 'yes'

I have tried all kinds of stuff... can you help.

Here is the array.

I tried string replace and a few others.  I think it is not a standard array.  Looks like the values are wrong.  Please help.

```
Array
(
    [0] => ATWS\AutotaskObjects\Entity Object
        (
            [Fields] =>
            [UserDefinedFields] => ATWS\AutotaskObjects\ArrayOfUserDefinedField Object
                (
                    [UserDefinedField] =>
                )

            [id] => 35
            [AccountID] => 218
            [AlertTypeID] => 1
            [AlertText] => test
        )

    [1] => ATWS\AutotaskObjects\Entity Object
        (
            [Fields] =>
            [UserDefinedFields] => ATWS\AutotaskObjects\ArrayOfUserDefinedField Object
                (
                    [UserDefinedField] =>
                )

            [id] => 36
            [AccountID] => 218
            [AlertTypeID] => 2
            [AlertText] => test2
        )

    [2] => ATWS\AutotaskObjects\Entity Object
        (
            [Fields] =>
            [UserDefinedFields] => ATWS\AutotaskObjects\ArrayOfUserDefinedField Object
                (
                    [UserDefinedField] =>
                )

            [id] => 37
            [AccountID] => 218
            [AlertTypeID] => 3
            [AlertText] => test3
        )

)
```

Bonus... Can it be done with this array?
OK Bonus question
what if it was

```
ATWS\AutotaskObjects\QueryResponse Object
(
    [queryResult] => ATWS\AutotaskObjects\ATWSResponse Object
        (
            [EntityResults] => ATWS\AutotaskObjects\ArrayOfEntity Object
                (
                    [Entity] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ATWS\AutotaskObjects\Entity Object
                             (                          
                                    [id] => 35
                                    [AccountID] => 218
                                    [AlertTypeID] => 1
                                    [AlertText] => test
                                )
```

Comment: you can do it like `$array[0]->AlertText = "yes";` and then check

Comment: Do you also want to replace `test2` with `yes`? Or should that be `yes2`? Or should it do nothing at all?

Comment: yes2.  I want it to look for the exact string

Comment: Even $array[0]->AlertText = "yes";
returns to me the same array.  No change.  It will not change the values.  I think it is something strange with the array.  Like Array in Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $entity->AlertText = str_replace("test", "yes", $entity->AlertText);
}
```

This will loop through your array ($entities), find 'test' in each entity's AlertText field and replace it with yes

Comment: THANK YOU. That was it... You got it.

Comment: OK Bonus question.

Comment: `$entities = $queryResponse->queryResult->EntityResults->Entity` ?

Comment: That is my first method but I need the original array.

Comment: I created the new array but now I want to update the original array

Answer (score -1):

For searching and replacing in arrays I use this -- Since there is no built-in function in PHP

```
$your_array = array_replace($your_array,
    array_fill_keys(
        array_keys($your_array, $value_to_replace),
        $replacement_value
    )
);
```

Comment: $final = array_replace($final,
    array_fill_keys(
        array_keys($final, $lookvalue),
        $replacevalue
    )
);

Comment: Does not change the array at all... I don't know why

Comment: Looks like you have an array of objects..  You need to loop through the array `$final` convert those `objects` to `arrays` and THEN run the code I provided inside your loop.